# Is there a way to inherit from two classes

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

My assignment:

Code a class called `SeniorWorker` which inherits from `Employee` class, in addition to `name`, `salary`, and `overtimePay`, it adds a `double` type data called `meritPay` which is calculated as 10% of the salary. It overrides `earning()` and `toString` methods to compute the total salary of `SeniorWorker` and return proper data of `SeniorWorker`, respectively.

Clarification: The assignment lets us use some example code from the book (Employee,RegularWorker,Manager, SeniorManager. java). My problem is that the `SeniorWorker` class inherits from the `Employee` class all those variable however the `Employee` class only includes the name variable and the rest of the variables except the `meritPay` are in the `RegularWorker` Class that why I'm wondering if I could inherit from both the `Employee` class and `RegularWorker` or do I need to do something else?

Code:

```
public class Employee {
   private String name;

   // Constructor
   public Employee(String name ) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName()
      { return name; }

   public   double earnings(){return 0.0;}
}



public class RegularWorker extends Employee {
   protected double salary, overtimePay;

   public RegularWorker( String name, double salary, double overtimePay) {
      super( name );  // call superclass constructor
      this.salary = salary;
      this.overtimePay = overtimePay;
   }

   public double earnings() { return salary + overtimePay; }    //override the method to return salary


   public String toString() {   //override the method to print the name
      return "Regular worker: " + getName();
   }
}
```

My Class:
So far i've just resorted to inheriting from the regularworker class(and it works) , however the assignment says i should inherit from employee class.

```
public class SeniorWorker extends RegularWorker  {
    public double meritPay;

public SeniorWorker(String name, double salary,double overtimePay, double meritPay)
{
    super(name,salary,overtimePay);
    this.meritPay = meritPay;
}

public double getMeritPay() {
    return meritPay;
}

public void calculateMeritPay(){
    meritPay = 0.10 * salary;

}

public double earnings() { return salary + overtimePay + meritPay; }    //override the method to return salary


public String toString() {  //override the method to print the name
   return "Senior Worker: " + getName();
}

}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Interfaces and Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes i cannot use interfaces since those come at a later chapter in our book. This chapter just deals with polymorphism and inheritance.

Comment: You can have SeniorWorker inherit from RegularWorker and argue that as RegularWorker inherits from Employee, SeniorWorker also inherits Employee. Or you can directly inherit from Employee and add the rest of the code needed to SeniorWorker.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the specified question

Comment: @BrianS -- I have edited your question which will put it in a reopen queue. Hopefully the moderator who reads it will agree that this isn't a duplicate and reopen it. In the mean time, I hope my answer helps a little.

Comment: When you cannot use interface, you may consider delegation, a basic object-oriented principal, also called consultation or aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

No, in java you can only inherit from one class. However, that class can inherit from another, and so on. You can extend multiple interfaces, which in java 8 could contain default method implementations (which could be default getters that return a predetermined value for the encapsulated attributes).

However, inheritance should only really be used for code sharing, and interfaces should only really be used for polymorphism.

Having said that, in your example, your RegularWorker is an Employee, so your SeniorWorker is a RegularWorker and is an Employee. Therefore, your SeniorWorker is inheriting (is extended from) Employee, as your assignment requests.

But, if you think about it, how can a senior worker also be a regular worker? They're not regular, they're senior. They may have been regular at one point in their career, but now they're senior, and not regular at all, despite having some stuff in common with regular employees. If you push the stuff from regularemployee up to employee, and have two descendants of employee, regular and senior, then you'll have sorted this mess out and probably earned extra points for being clever.

Comment: Java-8 interfaces cannot contain attributes.

Comment: Thanks, was trying to get through the answer quickly so shortcutted what I meant. I've fixed it now.